# Json with strange names

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

**First sorry for my English**

I have a problem with JSON.

Assume the following array in PHP

```
$msg['keyone'] = "bla1";
$msg['key_two'] = "bla2";
$msg['key-three'] = "bla3";
```

I convert it into JSON

```
json_encode($idioma);
```

Then  load it with AJAX / jQuery successfully

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "somepage.php",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.keyone);     // OK (bla1)
        alert(data.key_two);    // OK (bla2)
        alert(data.key-three);  // ERROR (obviously)!!!!            
    },
});
```

Exist any way/syntax to access "key-three".

**I can't rename the keys, I have to keep those ugly names.**

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access it like `data['key-three']`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the indexer style syntax

```
alert(data['keyone']);
alert(data['key_two']);
alert(data['key-three']);
```